# How to get write access to a folder?

Tags: python, windows, permissions, permission-denied

Basically I'm getting "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" when trying to copy using `shutil.copy` or `shutil.copyfile` to the iTunes folder (C:\Users{}\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Automatically Add to iTunes) where {} is the username

This is my code, and I just need to get permissions to the folder and I'm just lost, some people suggested `chown` or something but it apparently it's supported on Windows, some suggested:

```
args = ["icacls", directory, "/grant:r", 'LOCAL SERVICE:(OI)(CI)MF']
subprocess.check_call(args)
```

But it's still giving me permission errors, I'm fairly new to Python, and I really need to get past this "permission issue"

This is my full code (I tried using iTunesPath and Path2)

```
import getpass
import shutil
import subprocess

user = getpass.getuser()
iTunesPath: str = r"C:\Users\{}\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Automatically Add to iTunes" .format(user)
path2 ="C:\\Users\\{}\\Music\\iTunes\\iTunes Media\\Automatically Add to iTunes" .format(user)
args = ["icacls", iTunesPath, "/grant:r", 'LOCAL SERVICE:(OI)(CI)MF']
subprocess.check_call(args)
shutil.copyfile("D:\Freelance\iTunes Project\My songs\Clean Bandit - Solo ft. Demi Lovato.mp3", path2)
```

Comment: Please post the full actual Traceback error message.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem to write in *c:\Users\%your user%* directory. I guess your problem is backslashes in file path. Try this (notice `r"`):

```
shutil.copyfile(r"D:\Freelance\iTunes Project\My songs\Clean Bandit - Solo ft. Demi Lovato.mp3", path2)
```